# Hide slide number on title page

Tags: reveal.js

I am using

```
Reveal.initialize({
    slideNumber: true
})
```

Is there any possibility to hide the slide number on the title page?

Answer (score 2):

I have done it this way:

```
Reveal.addEventListener('slidechanged', (event) => {
    const isFirst = event.indexh === 0;
    Reveal.configure({ slideNumber: !isFirst });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a "slidechanged" event listener as below:

```js
Reveal.addEventListener('slidechanged', (event) => {
  const isSnOn = (event.currentSlide.dataset.hideSlideNumber !== 'true');
  Reveal.configure({ slideNumber: isSnOn });
});
```

Then you can use `data-hide-slide-number` to decide which sections to show/hide the slide number:

```html
<section data-hide-slide-number="true">
  ...
  The slide number is hidden in this section.
  ...
</section>
```